# N order derivative limit of natural logarithm

Tags: limits, derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function

Given:

$$f\left(x\right) = a\ln{\left( bx \right)}$$

Then:

$$f'\left(x\right) =  \frac{a}{x}$$
$$f''\left(x\right) =  \frac{-a}{x^2}$$
$$f'''\left(x\right) =  \frac{2a}{x^3}$$
$$f''''\left(x\right) =  \frac{-6a}{x^4}$$

In general, I think this is:

$$f^n\left(x\right) =  \frac{a\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\left(n-1\right)!}{x^n}$$

When $n\rightarrow\infty$, can this limit be expressed in a simple way? The limit of:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\left(n-1\right)!}{x^n}$$

Comment: $x^{n}/(n-1)! \to 0$ for every $x$.

Comment: @geetha290krm so I guess $\pm\infty$?

Comment: $-1^{n-1}$ should be $(-1)^{n-1}$

Comment: No, you can't have the limit being $\pm\infty$ on the real line. It doesn't converge.

Comment: Assuming @MartinR's correction.